# How to display values of a column as separate columns

Tags: python, dataframe, rows, transpose

I want to display the values in a column along with their count in separate columns

```
Dataframe is
Date     Name    SoldItem
15-Jul    Joe     TV
15-Jul    Joe     Fridge
15-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
15-Jul    Joe     TV
15-Jul    Joe     Fridge
15-Jul    Mary    Chair
15-Jul    Mary    Fridge
16-Jul    Joe     Fridge
16-Jul    Joe     Fridge
16-Jul    Tim     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Jimmy   Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
```

And I get the output as

```
Date      Name   Count
15-Jul     Joe       2
          Mary       1
16-Jul     Joe       2
```

I want the final output to be

```
Date    Joe    Mary 
15-Jul   2        1
16-Jul   2
```

below is the code

```
   fields = ['Date', 'Name', 'SoldItem']
   df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
   df_fridge = df.loc[(df['SoldItem'] == 'Fridge')]
   df_fridge_grp = df_fridge.groupby(["Date", "Name"]).size()
   print df_fridge_grp
```

If anyone can advise some pointers. I am guessing it can be done with loc, iloc, but am wondering then if my approach is wrong. Basically i want to count the values for certain types of items per person and then display that count against the name in a column display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
df_new = df[df['SoldItem'] == 'Fridge'].groupby(['Date', 'Name']).count()
df_new = df_new.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df_new)
```

**Output:**

```
       SoldItem     
Name        Joe Mary
Date                
15-Jul        2    1
16-Jul        2    0
```

Answer (score 3):

Does

```
df_fridge_grp.unstack()
```

Work?

Comment: Thanks! It does the job, but it has a decimal value, any way to remove that? for eg the values are 2.0, 1.0 instead of 2 and 1

Comment: That is because is an empty value, so the dtype is `float`. you could `.fillna(0).astype(int)` to fix that

Comment: @brentertainer - gave the complete solution. Thank you both though!